# Can I use jQuery to update the PHP session whilst typing?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, real-time

I have a textarea. I want to update a PHP session on the server whilst the user is typing. So as they are typing the session is updated. If they leave the page without submitting the form I can still call and return the information as it was "real-time session created"?

Looking like:

```
<form action="submit.php">

<textarea rows="10" id="question" name="question"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="save">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var formData = $("#question").val();
$(function() {
        function goSession(formData) {
            POST="http://updatesession.php.com/?do="+formData;
        }
        $("#question").change()({
            goSession();
        });
    });

</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php

session_start();

$sessionTheSavedQuestionForm=$_REQUEST["do"];
if($sessionTheSavedQuestionForm=="0" || $sessionTheSavedQuestionForm==""){
    $_SESSION["sessionTheSavedQuestionForm"]=0;
} else {
    $_SESSION["sessionTheSavedQuestionForm"]=$sessionTheSavedQuestionForm;
}

?>
```

Comment: Search for autocomplete - please check this with username forms etc.. Good way to ask though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of a timer and characters typed.

This is what I came up with. I haven't used JS in a while so it might look a bit rusty but it works.

Type something in the top textarea and watch it appear in the bottom textarea

http://jsfiddle.net/nfjAE/

Instead of sending the data to the textarea look at the [AJAX library provided by jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

I've updated my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nfjAE/3/ with a jQuery-free answer including a AJAX call example.

Comment: This is excellent. It (I read that it would destory the server though even though I use Nginx) maybe I should try an event listener when the move the mouse out or when they stop typing.

Answer (score 1):

You could send ajax call after a defined interval of time instead of each character typed to save in the session or database whatever you like. Use jquery ajax to send the data. You can find how to send ajax call [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
function SendData(event) {


/* get some values from elements on the page: */
var $form = $( this ),
    term = $form.find( 'input[name="s"]' ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( 'action' );

/* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
$.post( url, { s: term },
  function( data ) {

  }
);
}​

setInterval(SendData, 5000); // This will call above method after every 5 seconds
```

Comment: Don't overload us with your samples *NOT*

Comment: Can you show us some sample code as I provided is what he rudely means. Putting it nicely..

Comment: Sending ajax calls at each key is typically done for autocomplete and works very well.

Comment: @dystroy but it will destroy your webserver I guess. I do 500 keystrokes a minute. That is about 8 requests per second.

Answer (score 0):

you may try;

```
$("#question").keyup(function() {
var formData = $("#question").val();
 //AJAX REQUEST
});
```

and in your text area as;

```
<textarea rows="10" id="question" name="question"><?php echo $sessiondata; ?></textarea>
```